# Form and File Uploading in Django

Tags: django, forms, file-upload

I have been trying to figure out what is going wrong when I try to submit a form.
I get this response on the web page when I hit submit on the form:

```
Image:
    This field is required.
```

It seems to think I have not included an image in the form!

### **settings.py**

```
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/path/to/myproject/database/sqlite.db'),
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
...
MEDIA_ROOT = '/path/to/myproject/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'myapp',
)
```

### **models.py**

```
from PIL import Image
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

UPLOADER_CHOICES = (
    ('C', 'Common User'),
    ('N', 'Nutrition Kitchen'),
)

class Meal(models.Model):

    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug        = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    serves      = models.IntegerField()
    ingredients = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    instructions= models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    time_period = models.IntegerField()# in minutes
    uploader    = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=UPLOADER_CHOICES)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

### **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from meal.models import Meal

class MealForm(forms.Form):

    title       = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    image       = forms.ImageField()
    ingredients = forms.CharField(max_length=1000)
    instructions= forms.CharField(max_length=1000)
    time_period = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    serves      = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
```

### **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from meal.models import Meal
from meal.forms import MealForm

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MealForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = MealForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

### **upload.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if form.errors %}
        <p style="color: red;">
            Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
        </p>
{% endif %}
<div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.errors }}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            {{ form.as_table }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Save">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what I could be doing wrong? I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: Try changing class MealForm(forms.Form) to class MealForm(forms.ModelForm), everything else looks good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so it turned out that it was an issue with jQuery Mobile, which I didn't mention earlier. All I needed to do was change

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">
```

because jQuery was trying to handle the POST for me. Apparently when you POST to the same URL in Django and want to handle it manually, you must include the

```
data-ajax="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your forms.py

```
image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput())
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Nah, that didn't work. Same "This field is required" error. It's like it thinks I'm sending it a form without a file. Is there something I'm missing to tie the file to that POST or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

In your model you have

```
models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

This field is required.
Changing it to

```
models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
```

Will make it not required

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
form.save()
```

...does nothing. You should be either handling the cleaned_data from the form, or use the ModelForm that has a save() method.

[Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) |
[Django ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: So if I wanted all of the fields taken in from the ModelForm object saved to the corresponding fields in my Meal class to create a brand new Meal object in the database, how would I do that?

Comment: # in models.py
class MealForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Meal

...

# in views.py
form = MealForm(...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missed this,

```
class MealForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Meal 
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: I tried that, and it still doesn't work. I don't really understand what that would accomplish. I've already defined the fields in the form.

Comment: @DavidSawyer How about remove all fields in MealForm?

Comment: Nope. Man! It's still giving me that same error. Do I need to specifically save the image or something separately instead of just doing form.save()?

Comment: If you want to use the class Meta and specify the model, you need to change MealForm(forms.Form) to MealForm(forms.ModelForm). \

Answer (score 0):

Try using a **modelform** instead of a regular **form**.

```
class MealForm(forms.ModelForm): #Note, this is a Modelform, not a regular old form.
    class Meta: 
        model = Meal
```

Comment: I just switched that up, but it's still giving me the same error. Should I change anything in views.py?