# Django ModelForm ImageField Upload not working with Mobile Devices

Tags: django, mobile, django-forms, django-models

I am using a django ModelForm on a Model which contains an ImageField. I have included a generic version below with some details stripped out for clarity. This scheme is working fine for me and I am able to upload and display images from the model with no issues.

My problem in this case is that uploads are not working from mobile devices. I have tested on an Iphone 4, an Ipad 2 and an Android phone. None of the devices show any error and there is no error in the logs, however the image simply fails to upload.

Does anybody know what might be causing this issue or if this is a known problem with ModelForms and ImageFields? I would really like to continue using ModelForms as I have a lot of similar models and it makes maintenance easier but I am looking at custom options at this point.

Google has so far produced no useful information. If anyone can point in the right direction to figure this out it would be greatly appreciated.

My model looks like this (Some fields removed for brevity's sake):

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="room_images/")
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

My ModelForm looks like this with one custom TextArea field:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    notes = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model=MyModel
```

I am rendering the ModelForm with something similar to this (Object names changed to generic equivalents).

```
<form id="myForm" action="{% url my_url %}?param_one={{ object.pk }}&param_two={{ anotherobject.pk }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input id="saveSomething" class="nice small blue button" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

My view looks like this (Again some stuff stripped out for clarity):

```
@login_required
def object_edit(request):
    object_id = request.GET.get('param_one', None)
    object2_id = request.GET.get('param_two', None)

    if object_id:
        object = get_object_or_404(myModel, pk=object_id)
        if obejct.userprofile.user != request.user:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

    if object_id and object2_id != 'None':
        other_object = get_object_or_404(OtherModel, pk=object_id)
    else:
        other_object = OtherModel(object=object)

    if request.POST:
        form = myForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=other_object)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `ImageField` from the `ModelForm` to confirm it is the `ImageField` causing the problem?

Comment: The form is working fine, it's just the image that fails to upload so that wouldn't really help.

Comment: I would love to hear from someone that has successfully used ModelForm ImageField uploads with mobile devices.

Comment: Just to confirm does the image upload with a PC, laptop , mac?

Comment: Yes, uploads work great on non-mobile devices.

Comment: You can use something like `Ripple` for `Chrome` or something like `Firefox OS Simulator` for `Firefox` with `firebug` and you can see the console and the petitions to `django` and see the errors these tools help you so much to `debug` web applications for `mobiles`

Comment: What is your `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` for your django project?

Comment: Are you sure the file is being send over HTTP? Can you show us the actual POST request with some small file?

Comment: I actually got this working by switching to Ajax form submit. I will post the details later for anyone who might find it useful, but I will still award the bounty to anyone who can explain why the default ModelForm submit does not work with mobile.

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres Thanks for the heads up, those tools look useful.

Comment: @CIGuy Yes they do :D

Comment: Have you tried using a proxy for debugging, like WireShark or Fiddler? This would enable you to check the consistency of the structure of the POST request. On the other hand, what happens if you debug your Django object_edit view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at [Form and File Uploading in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812808/form-and-file-uploading-in-django) and [What does data-ajax="false" really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357088/what-does-data-ajax-false-really-do), it seems that your issue comes from jQuery Mobile.

JQM by default will try to load pages via ajax for improved user experience and transitions.

Apparently when you POST to the same URL in Django and want to handle it manually, you must include the

```
data-ajax="false"
```

In your case, this would mean changing your template to:

```
<form id="myForm"
      action="{% url my_url %}?param_one={{ object.pk }}&param_two={{ anotherobject.pk }}"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      method="post"
      data-ajax="false"> <!-- change is here -->
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input id="saveSomething" class="nice small blue button" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

From the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html):

> This tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the Ajax hash in the URL

I didn't try it myself, I just got the information from searching SO.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this myself, but your explanation sounds plausible and no one else has offered an alternative, so I am going to give you the bounty. Thanks for researching this, I will also mark as answer once I have a chance to test.